# Android: Is there a way to detect if a sound from SoundPool is still playing

Tags: android

I am writting a sound board. I would like it so when a person presses the button to play the sound, it would first see if a sound is stil playing.  So it can then stop that sound and start the new one.

Is thier a way to see if a sound id still playing, I'm jsing the following code to start my sound

```
// Sound code
void StartSound(int id)
{
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    float volume=(float) ((float)cGlobals.gVol/100.00);
    // Is the sound loaded already?

        soundPool.play(id, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class AudioSystem{
    /*
     * Checks whether the specified stream type is active.
     *
     * return true if any track playing on this stream is active.
     */
    public static native boolean isStreamActive(int stream, int inPastMs);
}
```

And for stream:

```
/** The audio stream for phone calls */
public static final int STREAM_VOICE_CALL = AudioSystem.STREAM_VOICE_CALL;
/** The audio stream for system sounds */
public static final int STREAM_SYSTEM = AudioSystem.STREAM_SYSTEM;
/** The audio stream for the phone ring */
public static final int STREAM_RING = AudioSystem.STREAM_RING;
/** The audio stream for music playback */
public static final int STREAM_MUSIC = AudioSystem.STREAM_MUSIC;
/** The audio stream for alarms */
public static final int STREAM_ALARM = AudioSystem.STREAM_ALARM;
/** The audio stream for notifications */
public static final int STREAM_NOTIFICATION = AudioSystem.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
/** @hide The audio stream for phone calls when connected to bluetooth */
public static final int STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO = AudioSystem.STREAM_BLUETOOTH_SCO;
/** @hide The audio stream for enforced system sounds in certain countries (e.g camera in Japan) */
public static final int STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED = AudioSystem.STREAM_SYSTEM_ENFORCED;
/** The audio stream for DTMF Tones */
public static final int STREAM_DTMF = AudioSystem.STREAM_DTMF;
/** @hide The audio stream for text to speech (TTS) */
public static final int STREAM_TTS = AudioSystem.STREAM_TTS;
```

Check for whatever type of audio stream you want to check. For example,  `AudioSystem.isStreamActive(STREAM_MUSIC, 0)` to check whether any music is active.

Comment: Android class `AudioSystem` is now replaced with [`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class and seems like there isn't such method like `isStreamActive()`.

Comment: Not working :( this method is not available any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isMusicActive()` method of `AudioManager`.