# Android: detect if sound from STREAM_VOICE_CALL is playing

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-mediasession, android-sound, android-audio-streams

I'm looking for a way to check if other applications are using the STREAM_VOICE_CALL (for example during a phone call or while listening a whatsapp voice note bringing the phone to the ear) (but in general we should find a way to choose any stream to monitor). I need this for using in Tasker, but that should be irrelevant (but should help other people with the same problem finding this).

Basically this was just perfect:

```
AudioSystem.isStreamActive(int stream, int inPastMs)
```

which could be used with any audio stream... in my case

```
AudioSystem.isStreamActive(STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 0)
```

Too bad AudioSystem is now replaced with [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class :( (info about AudioSystem in this other thread [Android: Is there a way to detect if a sound from SoundPool is still playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125431/android-is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-sound-from-soundpool-is-still-playing) )

Now we have **AudioManager.isMusicActive** which I have tried and it works flawlessly, but of course it refers to STREAM_MUSIC.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AudioSystem` is hidden API. You might need to use reflection to access it. Create extension for `AudioManager` and the use it as:

`audioManager.isStreamActive(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM)`

Implementation:

```
private val AUDIO_SYSTEM_IS_STREAM_ACTIVE: Method by lazy { Class.forName("AudioSystem").getDeclaredMethod("isStreamActive",
    Integer::class.javaPrimitiveType, Integer::class.javaPrimitiveType).also { it.isAccessible = true }
}

fun AudioManager.isStreamActive(stream : Int) : Boolean {
    require(stream in -1..11){
        "Stream type must be between -1 (DEFAULT) and 11 (ASSISTANT)"
    }
    return when (stream) {
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC -> {
            isMusicActive
        }
        AudioManager.STREAM_RING -> {
            ringerMode != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT
                    && AUDIO_SYSTEM_IS_STREAM_ACTIVE.invoke(this, stream, 0) as Boolean
        }
        else -> {
            AUDIO_SYSTEM_IS_STREAM_ACTIVE.invoke(this, stream, 0) as Boolean
        }
    }
}
```